# Ввод Readline ограничен 266 символами. Как исправить

Tags: c#

Использую для консоли следующий код (С#)

```
Console.Write("Код гугл ");
string google_map = Console.ReadLine();
```

Нужно ввести код карты Google, он достаточно длинный и не влазит(((
Очень долго искал ответ. Пожалуйста помогите

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это, как оказалось, [ограничение консоли](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081967/276994).

Попробуйте такой метод:

```
var bufsize = 320;
Stream stream = Console.OpenStandardInput(bufsize);
TextReader inReader = (stream == Stream.Null) ?
            StreamReader.Null :
            TextReader.Synchronized(
                new StreamReader(stream, Console.InputEncoding, false, bufsize, true));
Console.SetIn(inReader);
```

Выставьте размер буфера сколько нужно.

Код честно подсмотрен ILSpy'ем в методе [`Console.In`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,266).

Реальное ограничение — 254 символа: 256 байт размер буфера, плюс два байта резервируется под CRLF. Аналогично в случае ручной установки `bufsize` реальный размер будет на два байта меньше.

В реальности, сделать буфер *меньше*, чем 256, у меня не получилось.

---

Если вы захотите правильно обрабатывать символы других языков и выставите `Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;`, не забывайте, что ваш буфер будет расходовать по *два* байта на символ. Если вы, например, установите размер буфера в 320, то это даст всего лишь 160 юникодных символов (и будет поднято автоматически до 256).